# Pandas using previous element to calculate next element

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to implement the following formula in python using pandas

```
amS = ((1 - ratio) x (amS[-1]) + ratio x am)
```

`amS[-1]` is the value of the variable calculated at previous time instance and `amS` is the value to be calculated at current time instance dependent on input `am` and `ratio`. `am` is another pandas dataframe containing single column and ratio is a scalar.

What would be an efficient way to implement it?

Comment: I think you can check the pandas function [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand that recursive formula, you get

```
A_n = (1-r)^n A_0 + r * \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (1-r)^j S_{n-j}
```

where `A_n` and `S_n` are `n`th `amS` and `am` values, respectively and `r` is the ratio. `A_0` is the starting value for `amS`.

In code, this can be implemented with:

```
amS_values = (df.am
                .expanding()
                .apply(lambda s: (1-r)**s.size * A_0
                                 + r * ((1-r)**np.arange(s.size)[::-1] * s).sum()))
```

where `expanding` gives back `s` as the ever-increasing window and thereby `s.size` corresponds to `n` at each step.

e.g.

```
>>> df

   am
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   1

>>> r = 0.6
>>> A_0 = 3

>>> (df.am
       .expanding()
       .apply(lambda s: (1-r)**s.size * A_0
                         + r * ((1-r)**np.arange(s.size)[::-1] * s).sum()))

0    1.80000
1    1.92000
2    2.56800
3    1.62720
4    1.25088
```

Comment: I see an issue here amS[-1] = ((1 - ratio) x (amS[-2]) + ratio x am[-1]). I feel your implementation probably assumes amS[-1] = (1-ratio)*ams[-2].

Comment: @VishalPatil Not sure I'm following. If I apply the mathematical equation you posted in the question to the `df`, `r` and `A_0` I wrote at the end as an example, I see it is satisfied. What do you say i.e., what should have been the expected output for them?

Comment: Ok. got your point, you expanded it put the latter term into a summation. Seems right. Thank you!